# Does Visual Studio 2012 include the full Windows SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2012, winapi

If I've installed the Visual Studio 2012, do I need to install the Windows SDK, or are all tools / parts of the SDK included as part of the Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I'm sure there's always more to add....at least tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visual studio 2012 installer does not contain the full Windows SDK or Visual Studio 2012 SDK. these need to be installed separately.

Comment: What is the recommended Installation order? VS 2012, SDK or vice versa?

Comment: VS should be installed before SDK.
SDK's system requirements: Visual Studio Professional 20xx or higher

Answer (score 3):

Depends on which version of VS 2012 you have installed. Professional version and above include the Windows 8 SDK, so unless you are planning to develop applications for Windows XP or earlier versions of the OS, there is no need to install the SDK separately - you would already have it.

However, if you have installed VS 2012 Express, I would suggest referring to on-line documentation for clarification on this issue.

Comment: Do you have any links to said "on-line documentation"? At the moment this feels like half an answer.

Comment: Why do you respond a question by referring to not linked 'online documentation'? -1

Comment: Almost entirely pointless answer. You might have well said "google it". No good; downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

See this post for more information:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx

> "The DirectX SDK is now part of the Windows 8.0 SDK."
>
> "The Windows SDK for Windows 8 (aka Windows 8.0 SDK) is included with Visual Studio 2012, and is also available as a standalone package for use with Visual Studio 2010."