# Error in Cmake "The C compiler identification is unknown"

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I'm getting this error while configure on CMake

1. > The C compiler identification is unknown The CXX compiler identification is unknown CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35
   >   (project): No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found. CMake Error at
   >   CMakeLists.txt:35 (project): No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
   >   Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
   >   "E:/project/SFML-2.3.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
   >   "E:/project/SFML-2.3.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError log".

---

purpose : i just want to build the SFML with CMake and getting this error

system info: i'm using windows 10 64-bit OS ,

installed :

- visual studio 14 (2015)
- cmake-3.6.1-win64-x64
- SFML-2.3.2

Comment: Do you use the _Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt_? Usually, `cl.exe` (the compiler shipped with VS) isn't in the path.

Comment: i havn't tried that , can you tell me the procedure to apply this , and where ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The CXX compiler identification is unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632860/the-cxx-compiler-identification-is-unknown)

Answer (score -2):

I can't tell if your are not using it already but if you are on Windows I would use GUI for CMake:

[image]

You sholud see this window when trying to configure your build and you sholud be able to pick the correct generator (Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 in you case).

I'm getting this error when specyfing generator that is simply not installed on my machine.

Comment: Looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: i already tried ( selected this  visual studio 14 2015) but problem not solve

Comment: And i'm also cant able to install sdk on pc, when i 'm trying to install sdk i got "fatal error "

Comment: for using the cmake the sdk is necessary??