# Failure to build hadoop v2.7.1 in windows 7 64 bit with error : The C compiler identification is unknown , The CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: hadoop, sdk, cmake, maven-3, windows-7-x64

In windows 7 64 bit, I try to build hadoop version 2.7.1 as described in the thread:[Apache Hadoop 2.7.1 binary for Windows 64-bit platform](https://github.com/karthikj1/Hadoop-2.7.1-Windows-64-binaries)

i installed all needed software, for c compiler i use the c++ compiler of windows sdk 7.1 (visual studio 2010 isn't installed)

I run from Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt with release x64 the following command:

```
    mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

but the build failed with errors

```
     The C compiler identification is unknown
     -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
     CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
       No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.


     CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
     No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

The main setting of the command Prompt is:

```
    APPVER=6.1
    CL=/AI C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
    CommandPromptType=Native
    CURRENT_CPU=x64
    FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
    platform=x64
    PlatformToolset=Windows7.1SDK
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    sdkdir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\
    SESSIONNAME=Console
    TARGET_CPU=x64
    TARGET_PLATFORM=WIN7
    ToolsVersion=4.0
    USERDOMAIN=WIN7X64
    VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
    WindowsSDKDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\
    WindowsSDKVersionOverride=v7.1
```

The following is the console output:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Apache Hadoop HDFS 2.7.1
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-os) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
    ....
    ....

    main:
    [INFO] Executed tasks
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) @ hadoop-hdfs ---
    [INFO] Executing tasks

    main:
         [exec] -- The C compiler identification is unknown
         [exec] -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
         [exec] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
         [exec]   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
         [exec]
         [exec]
         [exec]
         [exec] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
         [exec]   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
         [exec]
         [exec]
         [exec]
         [exec] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
         [exec] See also "E:/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target
    /native/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
         [exec] See also "E:/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target
    /native/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  2.995 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  4.477 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  4.696 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.250 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  3.759 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  3.775 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  3.354 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  4.056 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  3.807 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SUCCESS [02:09 min]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [ 12.776 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [ 15.304 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.031 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. FAILURE [ 42.105 s]
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
    .....
    .....


    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 03:55 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-03T14:30:39+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 83M/494M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .....
    ....
```

I googled like: [The CXX compiler identification is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632860/the-cxx-compiler-identification-is-unknown)
but i didn't find a solution for my problem

How to configure cmake or maven to avoid this error and build hadoop 2.7.1 using windows sdk 7.1 ?

Should i need to install visual studio 2010?

What i missed to do?

Comment: What's your CMake version? If it is older than your SDK 7.1, it does not recognize it.

Comment: CMake version: cmake-3.7.0-win64-x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build failure is due to  the issue of the break support of cmake version 3.7.1 for Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7.

i used cmake-3.6.3-win64-x64 and the build success, view the screenshot:

[image]

I post the Issue #16483 at [3.7.1 broke support for Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16483)

The Cmake issue is planeed to be resolved in Cmake version 3.7.2

I used the following software tools:

- apache-maven-3.3.9
- cmake-3.6.3-win64-x64
- cygwin64
- jdk1.7.0_79
- protoc-2.5.0-win32